# Исправить фильтр

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Подскажите пожалуйста почему ильтр не работает? я ипользовал не стандартный filter, а обычную функцию. Такой способ фильтровать устарел или я что-то сделал неправильно?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8w0qg31x/4/)

html:

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="lsController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="date in dateArr">
                <span class="date">{{date | dateFormatter}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>          
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('App', [])
    .controller('lsController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.dateArr = [
            '10.10.2016',
            '11.10.2016',
            '12.10.2016',
            '13.10.2016',
            '14.10.2016',
            '15.10.2016'
        ];  

        $scope.dateFormatter = function(date) {
            return date.slice(0, 5);
        }                   
    });
```

Использую angular 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш вариант вполне имеет право на жизнь, но лучше использовать классический фильтр.

В вашем случае стоит сделать так

```
<span class="date">{{dateFormatter(date)}}</span>
```

Для того чтобы оставить только дату и месяц, лучше воспользоваться более "умным" способом разделения даты например `return date.split('.').slice(0,2).join('.')` тогда даже однозначные даты и месяцы не приведут к ошибкам

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, Вам необходимо определить новый [фильтр в модуле](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11), вот так:

```
app.filter('dateFormatter',function(){
    return function(date) {
        return date.slice(0,5);
    }; 
})
```

фильтр должен возвратить функцию-обработчик

https://jsfiddle.net/8w0qg31x/6/